# tailwind animation in config transformOrigin: 'center'

Tags: animation, rotation, tailwind-css, config, centering

I'm trying to rotate a button using animation in Tailwind but can not understand where to put a transformOrigin: 'center' in tailwind.config

```
keyframes: {
        rotate: {
          "0%": {
            transform: "rotate(0) translateY(0)",
            transformOrigin: 'center',
          },
          "100%": {
            transform: "rotate(180deg) translateY(-40px)",
            transformOrigin: 'center',}
        },
      },
      animation: {
        rotate: "rotate 1s forwards"
      }
```

This doesn't work

Comment: I also tryed set a className="animate-rotate origin-center" - it rotates but not from center point

Answer (score 0):

As per [the CSS specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-origin-property) the default value of `transform-origin` is `50% 50%` which is the same as `center`, so unless in the unlikely event that you have applied some other `transform-origin` value to the button, you shouldn't need to declare the value at all.

To have it rotate from the center point, you'd need to reverse the order of the `transform` functions so that `translateY()` is applied **before** `rotate()`:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
        rotate: {
          "0%": {
            transform: "translateY(0) rotate(0)",
          },
          "100%": {
            transform: "translateY(-40px) rotate(180deg)",
          }
        },
      },
      animation: {
        rotate: "rotate 1s forwards"
      }
    },
  },
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="pt-20">
  <button class="animate-rotate">Foo</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed the order in transform: { } ,and now (it's very strange) the button is shifting up (was down) and rotation is good ! thanks

Comment: A negative `translateY()` moves up. To have it move down, use a positive `translateY()`.